# android login getting errors with async task

Tags: android

Hi Im trying to use the Async task to utilize a basic login system I got from a tutorial (to just learn). Im having issues though. To get over the android.os.networkexception I use async but I'm sure I'm using it completely incorrectly in this situation. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.toknapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class login2 extends Activity {
    EditText un;
    TextView error;
    Button ok;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                GetData task = new GetData();
                task.execute();


            }
        });
    }

    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
            //String valid = "1";
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://tokn.me/android_merchant_login.php", postParameters);
                String res=response.toString();
               // res = res.trim();
                res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");                              
                //error.setText(res);

               if(res.equals("1"))
                    error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                else
                    error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password"); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                un.setText(e.toString());
            }


            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while exec
uting doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:27
8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSet
Exception(FutureTask.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(
FutureTask.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
(FutureTask.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTas
k.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(Asy
ncTask.java:208)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWo
rker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worke
r.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThr
eadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch i
ts views.
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRoo
tImpl.java:3903)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(Vie
wRootImpl.java:708)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInPa
rent(ViewRootImpl.java:757)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGr
oup.java:4006)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8432)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(Text
View.java:4318)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.j
ava:7669)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanA
dded(TextView.java:8018)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanA
dded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:898)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(S
pannableStringBuilder.java:614)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(S
pannableStringBuilder.java:520)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection
.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection
.java:87)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.in
itialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java
:3243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java
:3109)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java
:78)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java
:3084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at com.example.toknapp.login2$GetData.doInBackgr
ound(login2.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at com.example.toknapp.login2$GetData.doInBackgr
ound(login2.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:26
4)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
(FutureTask.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1188):        ... 5 more
W/ActivityManager(   85):   Force finishing activity com.example.toknapp/.toknap
p
W/WindowManager(   85): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21015
W/InputManagerService(   85): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.i
nternal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@417c3938 (uid=10040 pid=1188)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1188): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   85): setKernelCountSet(10004, 1) failed with
errno -2
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   85): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with
errno -2
I/Process ( 1188): Sending signal. PID: 1188 SIG: 9
W/InputManagerService(   85): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: co
m.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4135b3d8
I/ActivityManager(   85): Process com.example.toknapp (pid 1188) has died.
W/BinderNative(   85): Uncaught exception from death notification
W/BinderNative(   85): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registere
d: com.android.server.TextServicesManagerService$InternalServiceConnection@417c4
b78
W/BinderNative(   85):  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedA
pk.java:888)
W/BinderNative(   85):  at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.jav
a:1147)
W/BinderNative(   85):  at com.android.server.TextServicesManagerService$SpellCh
eckerBindGroup.cleanLocked(TextServicesManagerService.java:592)
W/BinderNative(   85):  at com.android.server.TextServicesManagerService$SpellCh
eckerBindGroup.removeListener(TextServicesManagerService.java:575)
W/BinderNative(   85):  at com.android.server.TextServicesManagerService$Interna
lDeathRecipient.binderDied(TextServicesManagerService.java:662)
W/BinderNative(   85):  at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:41
7)
W/BinderNative(   85):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: getting errors? how many? which are they? post the logcat.

Comment: dont set text while in doInBackground(), remove it from there if u want to set text then change it in postExecute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever happens inside doInBackground() is actually running on a separate thread and not on UI thread. If you want to change some UI element like setText() or setting image resources or anything, you should be doing it in UI thread.

onPreExecute and onPostExecute() methods of AsyncTask run on the UI thread. This is how the flow is in the order -

```
onPreExecute() -> doInBackground() -> onPostExecute()
```

So whatever the setting UI elements you're doing in doInBackground do it in onPostExecute().

So basically, your doInBackground should only be doing connecting to the server and getting response. Let the onPOstExecute() handle the rest (setting text stuff).

We need to use publishProgress(param) method to update UI thread, the sample provided in android documention is helpful.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#pubmethods
please see the code snippet under "Usage" section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html), This will give you an idea about async task, there are three phases in asynctask,(1) preExecute(),(2)doInBackground(), (3) postExecute().  You can not change any controls while its in doInBackground(), you can change the controls in postExecute() or preExecute()...!!  In addition if you still want to change the UI while the response havent come yet,then to call run on UI thread you can do it in publishProgress() and onProgressUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to update the UI from the doInBackground method which doesn't not run on the UI thread. You can't touch the view 'error' from there.

When you use AsyncTask you can update the UI only through:

- onPreExecute
- onPostExecute
- publishProgress/onProgressUpdate